# Cant add user from front end with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

Im working on a frontend only system, and i need a way for admins to add a user from the front end.

However i cant seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

here is my code im calling it through AJAX

```js
$( "#createuser" ).click(function() {
  var getusername = $("#usernameset").val();
  var getpassword = $("#userpasswordset").val();
  var getemail = $("#useremailset ").val();
  var getlocation = $(".country_id_set").html();

  adduserfrontend(getusername,getpassword,getemail,getlocation);
});

function adduserfrontend(username,password,email,location) {
  $.ajax ({
      url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/example/functions.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          action: 'addnewuser',
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
          'email': email,
          'location': location,
      },
      success: function (results) {
          console.log( 'New user was added' );
      },
      fail: function(data) {
          console.log( data.responseText );
          console.log( 'Request Failed' + data.statusText );
      }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="adduser">
<label>Username: </label><input type="text" id="usernameset" name="usernameset" placeholder="New User">
<label>Password: </label><input type="text" id="userpasswordset" name="userpasswordset" placeholder="Enter Password">
<label>Email: </label><input type="text" id="useremailset" name="useremailset" placeholder="example@example.com">
<button id="createuser">Create User</button>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```html
function addnewuser() {
  $username = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] );
  $pasword = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['password'] );
  $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] );
  $location = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['location'] );
  // add new user
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $pasword, $email );
  $user_id_role = new WP_User($user_id);
  $user_id_role->location($location);

    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_addnewuser', 'addnewuser' );
```

Comment: Please clarify what **exactly** is not working with the given code

Comment: Ajax posts to functions.php
How ever nothing happens from there.
User is not added to the wordpress install.

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: in my php, i have tried setting the username,password,email and location within the php, so it doesnt need the $_Post information and still nothing.

Other then that. im not sure what else to try and debug it with.

Comment: @JohannesGrandy can you explain?

No errors in console.log it passes correctly.

Comment: you have to enable cross-domain resource origin(CORS), do console and check if that is the problem...

Comment: set up your error function of jquery ajax as well along with success and fail. see if you end up in error function

Comment: Do you need ' around your `action:` ?

Comment: your data is also incorrect , put `'` around `action`.

Comment: Ok so i tried your suggestion @GaganDeep , and i get this result
Request Failedundefined

Also for action
If i set it with 'action' same problem. still nothing.

I have another script running for editing users with action set up the same way so its not the issue

Comment: add the content type option to your ajax call `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: thanks, but its still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function user_profile_enqueue() {

    // Register script for localization
    wp_register_script (
        'user-profile-mod',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    // Localize script so we can use $ajax_url
    wp_localize_script (
        'user-profile-mod',
        'user_meta_ajax',
        array(
            'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );



    // Enqueue script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile-mod' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'user_profile_enqueue' );
```

the poster above was correct. i needed to include admin-ajax.php,
But i went with it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in JS code

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>
```

Also you have used the wrong way to call ajax in wordpress
Use this method

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_addnewuser', 'addnewuser' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_addnewuser', 'addnewuser' );

    function addnewuser() {
        $username = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] );
  $pasword = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['password'] );
  $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] );
  $location = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['location'] );
  // add new user
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $pasword, $email );
  $user_id_role = new WP_User($user_id);
  $user_id_role->location($location);

    exit;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, didnt notice that.
How ever its still not passing. im going to have to find another way of doing this.

Comment: Did you try that? Takes 10 seconds to check that whether you have a space or not, it will still get the right element... Please don't post answers before being sure it will work **and** help OP.

Comment: I did try it yes,
How ever it didnt solve the issue.

Im not sure what exactly is wrong with the setup i have.

But its not adding any user.

Comment: Did you have installed any membership plugin?

Comment: No, its a clean install of wordpress besides jquery

How ever something intresting.

I just tried adding the php to start on init
with the username, password, email, and location set with "example" instead of pulling from post

and it added the user correctly. weird.

Comment: @Mic my question "Did you try that?" was for Ravi Kumar... not for you. Because obviously this is not going to fix your issue.